# removed Class and want to add it back

Tags: javascript, html, css

I coded a simple javascript "clearning Shopping List" code.

I was able to remove the shopping list and add two messages:
One says that the shopping list has been cleared and one pops up a button that asks if it was a mistake and you want to undo your change.

Now my problem is that when you press the "Undo" button the class doesn't get added back.

```js
// javascript

var shoppingList = document.querySelector(".shoppingCart");
var toggleButton = document.querySelector("button.showList");
var clearedBox = document.querySelector(".clearedBox");
var clearedUndo = document.querySelector("button.clearedUndo");

//Toggle Shopping Cart
toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    shoppingList.remove(".shoppingCart");
    clearedBox.style.display = "block";
    toggleButton.remove("button.showList");
});

//Undo Removal
clearedUndo.addEventListener("click", () => {
   clearedUndo.createClass(".shoppingCart");
});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left:30px;
}
.clearedBox {
    display:none;
}
.clearedMessage {
    background:#D66A68;
    color: white;
    padding:10px;
    width:260px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.clearedUndo {
    background:#1C77C3;
    color: white;
    padding:5px;
    width:225px;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>index.html</h1>
        <button class="showList">Show</button>
        
        <div class="shoppingCart">
            <ul>
                <li>Milk</li>
                <li>Eggs</li>
                <li>Juice</li>
                <li>Pasta</li>
                <li>Water</li>
                <li>Donuts</li>
            </ul>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearedBox">
        <p class="clearedMessage">Your Shopping cart is now cleared!</p>
        <button class="clearedUndo">Accidental? Undo your change!</button>
        </div>
        
        
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would assume this part is wrong:

```
//Undo Removal
clearedUndo.addEventListener("click", () => {
   clearedUndo.createClass(".shoppingCart");
});
```

Comment: Is this `React.createClass()`? Since Normal DOM elements do not have a createClass method. Might be advisable to update your question to make it clear this is a react project. Which also would give a hint at the problem, since afaik, `React.createClass()` is not added to elements, but is a static of the React object. And react is not imported in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you remove it, it's gone, and if you want to put it back with JavaScript then all that markup really needs to be re-inserted, so I'd consider just hiding and showing the elements as needed, by changing the JS to this:

```
var shoppingList = document.querySelector(".shoppingCart");
var toggleButton = document.querySelector("button.showList");
var clearedBox = document.querySelector(".clearedBox");
var clearedUndo = document.querySelector("button.clearedUndo");

//Toggle Shopping Cart
toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    shoppingList.style.display = "none";
    clearedBox.style.display = "block";
    toggleButton.style.display = "none";
});

//Undo Removal
clearedUndo.addEventListener("click", () => {
    shoppingList.style.display = "block";
    clearedBox.style.display = "none";
    toggleButton.style.display = "block";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE**

1. Don't use the `elem.remove` .Because if you undo the action no elements are present .For alternatively you can use [`elem.classList.toggle`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

```js
// javascript

var shoppingList = document.querySelector(".shoppingCart");
var toggleButton = document.querySelector("button.showList");
var clearedBox = document.querySelector(".clearedBox");
var clearedUndo = document.querySelector("button.clearedUndo");

//Toggle Shopping Cart
toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  shoppingList.classList.toggle('hide')
  clearedBox.classList.toggle('show')
  //toggleButton.remove("button.showList");
});

//Undo Removal
clearedUndo.addEventListener("click", () => {
 shoppingList.classList.toggle('hide')
  clearedBox.classList.toggle('show')
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.clearedBox {
  display: none;
}
.hide{
 display: none;
}
.show{
 display: block;
}
.clearedMessage {
  background: #D66A68;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 260px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.clearedUndo {
  background: #1C77C3;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 225px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>index.html</h1>
  <button class="showList">Show</button>

  <div class="shoppingCart">
    <ul>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Eggs</li>
      <li>Juice</li>
      <li>Pasta</li>
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Donuts</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clearedBox">
    <p class="clearedMessage">Your Shopping cart is now cleared!</p>
    <button class="clearedUndo">Accidental? Undo your change!</button>
  </div>


  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```